# Regex to find a specific string that is not in a HTML attribute

Tags: javascript, html, regex

My case is: I have a string with HTML elements:

```
<a href="something+specific_string" title="testing">This is a text and "specific_string"</a>
```

I need a Regex to match only the one that is not in a HTML attribute.

This is my current Regex, it works but it gives a false positive when the string is wrapped by double quotes

```
((?!\"[\w\s]*)specific_string(?![\w\s]*\"))
```

I have tried the following Regex:

```
((?!\"[\w\s]*)specific_string(?![\w\s]*\"))
```

It works but it gives a false positive when the string is wrapped by double quotes

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to achieve? Why do you have to work with the entire HTML?

Comment: @Wimanicesir I have a field where users can store HTML as a string. When handling it, I need to replace `specific_string` with another HTML tag, but only when it's not an attribute, otherwise it'll break the HTML layout

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get what's inside the   tag you might be trying to use the split() tool; to cut the string every >" or "<" basically like this:

```js
let string = "<a href='something+specific_string' title='testing'>This is a text and 'specific_string'</a>";

string = string.split('>');
string = string[1].split('<');

console.log(string)
```

So, when you want to manipulate it, just use position 0 of the string. Is not regex like u wnat, but is an idea

Answer (score 0):

Though it can suffice in simple cases, you should know it's [often](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la) that RegExp is ill-suited for parsing HTML, and depending on environment you could be better off using more robust techniques. (There's http://htmlparsing.com/ dedicated to the topic but yet it doesn't discuss JS.)

That said, the following works in Chrome 107 and Node 16.13.

```js
(s=>s.match(/(?<=>[^<]*|^[^<]*)specific_string/))
('<a href="something+specific_string" title="testing">This is a text and "specific_string"</a>')
```

It uses look-behind. In lieu of that you could use `/(>[^<]*|^[^<]*)(specific_string)/` and compensate index/lengths to get the position of a match...

---

As you [answer in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74377763/regex-to-find-a-specific-string-that-is-not-in-a-html-attribute/74378041#comment131305802_74377763) that you'll replace in user-provided HTML, I encourage you to consider security implications (namely [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)).

Back on the topic of parsing HTML w/o RegExp we obviously have the techniques in a web browser and I couldn't stop myself writing a quick and dirty textNode replacer in web JS, working in Chrome 107:

```js
((html, fun) => {
  const el = document.createElement('body')
  el.innerHTML = html
  const X = new XPathEvaluator, R = X.evaluate('//*[text()]', el)
  const A = []; for (let n; n = R.iterateNext();) A.push(n) // mutating el while iterating XPathResult is illegal
  for (let n of A) fun(n)
  return el.innerHTML})
('<a href="something+specific_string" title="testing">This is a text and "specific_string"</a>',
  n => n.innerHTML = n.innerHTML
    .replace(/specific_string/, '<b>replaced</b>'))
```